# How to style Javascript window.open element

Tags: javascript

I want the user to click a link and a new window opens with a specific size and position.

I have achieved this, but would like the 'terms and conditions' link to behave like a normal link. i.e. hover states, mouse to change into a hand.

```html
<body>
  <a onclick="termsWin()"> terms and conditions</a>
  <script>
    function termsWin() {
      window.open("myurl", "", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=100,left=250,width=400,height=600");
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the `href` attribute to make it a hyperlink. Without it, it's just an anchor.

```html
    <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="termsWin()"> terms and conditions</a>
    <script>
    function termsWin() {
    window.open("myurl","","toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=100,left=250,width=400,height=600");
    }
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Gonna be frustrating for anyone who wants to use the context menu. (Also, clicking it will have the additional effect of scrolling to the top.)

Comment: The only reason you'd use the context menu it to open the link in another window, which is what will happen here anyway. Plus, the OP isn't asking for a better way to do this, the OP is asking why he's not getting typical hyperlink behavior.

Comment: Bold claim. Wrong, too. Commonly, these days, people will want to open a page in another *tab*, which is specifically what the `window.open` will try not to do. They’ll also want to copy the link, or save the target page. Dragging it somewhere won’t work. Hovering over it to see where the link will go won’t work. It won’t work before the JavaScript has loaded. Ctrl+clicking it won’t work. Middle-clicking it won’t work. And so on. All of this is part of behaving like “a normal link”.

Comment: Again, the OP didn't ask for a better way, the OP asked why typical hyperlink formatting wasn't being applied. This answer answers that question.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a correct and useful link to your page:

```html
<a href="myurl" target="_blank">terms and conditions</a>
```

Then add your JavaScript on top of it, cancelling the default link event with `return false`:

```html
<a href="myurl" target="_blank" onclick="termsWin(this.href); return false">terms and conditions</a>

<script>
function termsWin(url) {
    window.open(url, "", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=100,left=250,width=400,height=600");
}
</script>
```

Then delete the JavaScript and go back to the first version, because opening tiny, limited windows for stuff only on the platforms that still even allow you to do it is annoying and useless.

Comment: If you are going to go down this road, lose the inline event handling completely.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: That’s what I said, isn’t it?

Comment: `<a href="myurl" target="_blank" onclick="termsWin(this.href); return false">` <-- You tell me.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: “Then delete the JavaScript and go back to the first version …” Result: no inline event handlers.